# I need help for coding a simple an N-ary tree

Tags: rust, n-ary-tree

The tree looses its elements???

I tried several ways to solve this problem but I didn't succeed.
I think that the problem could be due to the `clone()` of the argument to `Vec::push()`, but I dont know how to manage it differenly.

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, fmt::Debug, rc::Rc};

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Tree<T>>>>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Tree<T>
where
    T: Clone,
    T: Debug,
{
    elm: T,
    child: Vec<Tree<T>>,
    parent: Link<T>,
}

impl<T> Tree<T>
where
    T: Clone,
    T: Debug,
{
    pub fn new(elm: T) -> Self {
        Self {
            elm: elm,
            child: Vec::<Tree<T>>::new(),
            parent: None,
        }
    }
    pub fn add(&mut self, elm: T) -> Self {
        let new_tree = Tree {
            elm: elm,
            child: Vec::<Tree<T>>::new(),
            parent: Some(Rc::new(RefCell::new(self.clone()))),
        };

        self.child.push(new_tree.clone());
        new_tree
    }

    pub fn print(&mut self) {
        println!("elm={:?}", self.elm);
        if 0 != self.child.len() {
            for elm in self.child.iter() {
                elm.clone().print();
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut tree0 = Tree::new(0);
    tree0.add(1);
    tree0.add(2);
    let mut tree3 = tree0.add(3);

    tree3.add(4);
    tree3.add(5);

    tree0.print();
}
```

Comment: Why are you learning Rust by implementing data structures? This is not a good idea.

Comment: What other approche do you propose me.

Comment: To learn Rust? Implement some project. Data structures touch the most complex aspects of Rust and this is not a task for a beginner. If you want, make sure to read https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/.

Comment: I can recommend [this](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/) version of ["The book"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) for learning Rust and reserve "Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists" (https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/) for afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a parent link which is `Rc<RefCell>` but have bare children links. If you want (safe) parent links, you need both to be `Rc<RefCell>`.

Here's a possible implementation:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, fmt::Debug, rc::Rc};

type Link<T> = Rc<RefCell<Tree<T>>>;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Tree<T> {
    elm: T,
    child: Vec<Link<T>>,
    parent: Option<Link<T>>,
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    pub fn new(elm: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Self {
            elm: elm,
            child: Vec::new(),
            parent: None,
        }))
    }
    pub fn add(this: &Rc<RefCell<Self>>, elm: T) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        let new_tree = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Tree {
            elm: elm,
            child: Vec::new(),
            parent: Some(Rc::clone(this)),
        }));

        this.borrow_mut().child.push(Rc::clone(&new_tree));
        new_tree
    }

    pub fn print(&self)
    where
        T: Debug,
    {
        println!("elm={:?}", self.elm);
        for elm in self.child.iter() {
            elm.borrow().print();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let tree0 = Tree::new(0);
    Tree::add(&tree0, 1);
    Tree::add(&tree0, 2);
    let tree3 = Tree::add(&tree0, 3);

    Tree::add(&tree3, 4);
    Tree::add(&tree3, 5);

    tree0.borrow().print();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3fb140d97e08c34394a72bff5abd3f6b).

Yes, this is ugly. You can (and should) wrap the top-level `Tree` with a struct that encapsulates the operations. It'll still be ugly and fragile.

The correct way to implement a tree with parent links in Rust is either as a graph, by using a graph library such as [`petgraph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph), or with unsafe code. Either way you should not implement it yourself as a beginner. There are better ways to learn Rust.

Comment: Thank a lot for this answer. I did not find this solution alone. Why do you say it's an ugly and fragile solution?

Comment: @YaOo The solution is not ugly nor fragile, the entire tree implementation is (because of the `Rc<RefCell>`). And if you want to understand the disadvantages, look at https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/fourth-final.html. The considerations there apply here too.